Jupyter Notebook, Jupyter Lab - How do I fix autocomplete suggestion window not being displayed properly (size issue)?
bug
bug demo.gif
Jupyter Notebook and Jupyter Lab autocomplete suggestion window gets too small once I almost type it out and the window doesn't let me resize as well.
I tried restarting Jupyter Notebook/Lab.
This is a bit annoying, and I'd be happy if someone helps me with this.

Bug gets fixed in versions Jupyter lab 4.1 and Notebook 7.1
Update corresponding packages to resolve issue.
